# Syntax Error: fstrings in DataBricks Python notebook

Tags: python, syntax-error, databricks, f-string

I keep getting the below syntax error when trying to use `fstring` in a DataBricks Python notebook.

What am I missing?

**Cell:**

```
%python

test = 'yay'
f'This works, {test}!'
```

**Results:**
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

[image]

**Running this same code in a Jupyter notebook returns just fine.**
[image]

**EDIT 1:**

```
%python

import sys

sys.version

'3.5.2 (default, Nov 12 2018, 13:43:14) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
```

Comment: I'm not sure what Databricks is, but what version of Python is it running? F-strings are semi-new.

Comment: Check what version it's using.  You can get the version by first doing `import sys`, then look at `sys.version`.

Comment: `3.5.2`... and now I see that they are not available until `3.6`.. Case closed.